# Python + GNU/readline bindings: keep my sort order

Tags: python, readline, libreadline

GNU/readline seems to sort my data no matter what I do. My code code looks just like in the documentation:

```
tags = [tag.lower() for tag in tags]
def completer(text, state):
    text = text.lower()
    options = [tag for tag in tags if tag.startswith(text)]
    try:
        return options[state]
    except IndexError:
        return None

readline.set_completer(completer)
readline.parse_and_bind('tab: menu-complete')
```

If my tags are `['jarre', 'abba', 'beatles']`, I keep getting `['abba', 'beatles', 'jarre']`. How can I force my order to be kept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is dedicated option for this: [rl_sort_completion_matches](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#IDX389). It sorts the options lexicographically, and removes duplicates - so if you override it, you'll need to take care of duplicates yourself.

However, it's not accessible from the Python's bindings.

Fortunately it doesn't mean you can't get it to work - you can change it using `cdll` or `ctypes`. Since it's a global variable rather than a function, I'll use `in_dll` method:

```
import ctypes
rl = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libreadline.so')
sort = ctypes.c_ulong.in_dll(rl, 'rl_sort_completion_matches')
sort.value = 0
```

After this, the matches should be retrieved in correct order.

This isn't a very portable method, unfortunately - for example, in Windows you should use `.dll` suffix rather than Linux's `.so`. However, focusing on `ctypes` portability is outside the scope of this answer.